# How do can I get rid of the blank lines that are created c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, counter

---

Edit:
Thank you all for the quick and helpful replies. I got it working now. It was because I had to reset the counter.

---

I have come to ask for help as my professor is not giving me the help I need. I am new to c++ and I am trying to program a program that displays all the integers from 1 to 100 that are divisible by 6 or 7, but not both. and I have to display 5 numbers per row. I got it working except I have blank lines forming in certain areas. I don't know if it's because of how I set up the counter or what.

Here is what I got.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int counter = 0; // Counter for creating new lines after 5 numbers
    for (int numRange = 1; numRange <= 100; ++numRange) // Starts the loop of number 1 to 100
    {
        if (numRange % 6 == 0 || numRange % 7 == 0) // Makes the numbers divisible by 6 and 7
        {
            cout << numRange << " "; // Displays the output of the divisible numbers
            counter++; // Starts the counter

        }
        if (counter % 5 == 0) // using the counter to create new lines after 5 numbers displayed
        {
            cout << endl; // Creates a new line
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is what is outputted:

```
6 7 12 14 18


21 24 28 30 35
36 42 48 49 54

56 60 63 66 70

72 77 78 84 90
91 96 98
```

and this is what it's supposed to look like

```
  6   7 12 14 18 
21 24 28 30 35 
36 48 49 54 56 
60 63 66 70 72 
77 78 90 91 96 
98
```

Comment: A details of actual vs desired output might be useful.

Comment: What happens now and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Why not use `if (counter == 5)` for the test?  (You'll need `counter = 0;` reset in the body.)

Comment: `for (int numRange = 1; ...` looks wrong. Don't you want `for (int numRange = 0; `?

Comment: When your counter doesn't gets updated, it will print new lines. For example, for numRange=19 and 20, the counter still will be 5 and it will print new lines

Comment: You're not resetting the counter in the code so if the first `if` does not get called after you find a number divisible by 5, it prints a newline until the counter gets incremented again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you're seeing is due to the fact that you are checking for "5 outputs" on **every** loop, rather than only on ones where a number has been output! So, to fix *this* issue (there are others), put the `counter % 5 == 0` test inside the preceding `if` block:

```cpp
    for (int numRange = 1; numRange <= 100; ++numRange) // Starts the loop of number 1 to 100
    {
        if (numRange % 6 == 0 || numRange % 7 == 0) // Makes the numbers divisible by 6 and 7
        {
            cout << numRange << " "; // Displays the output of the divisible numbers
            counter++; // Increments the counter
            if (counter % 5 == 0) // Only need this if we have done some output!
            {
                cout << endl; // Creates a new line
            }
        }
    }
```

Another problem is that, in this requirement:

> that are divisible by 6 or 7, but not both

your code doesn't check for the "but not both" part (but that's not the 'title' question, and I'm not going to do ***all*** your homework in one fell swoop).